# Can Tensorflow `AudioClassifier` be used to extract/save raw data to a `.wav` file?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have an application called the ["cat doorbell"](https://github.com/cat-doorbell-v2) which lets me know when our cat wants in the house.  It works fine, but I need to gather some meow sound snippets for another project.

Looking at my code [here](https://github.com/cat-doorbell-v2/cat-doorbell-v2-rpi-python/blob/9363d6a49d450f341875ad8057d72f2ec4d6ff09/raspberry-pi/doorbell.py#L214), I was wondering if it is possible extract raw audio and save it to a `.wav` file. Can that be done?